# JQueryUI styles sometimes lost in Ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am loading some dynamic content into a `div` container and re-apply the JQueryUI styles to my buttons using the following (as was discussed on this forum before):

```
$('#menu li a').click(function(){
    $('#main').load('load.php ' + $(this).attr('href'));
    $.ajax({
        success: function(){
            $("#button").button();
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

It all works fine most of the time. Only sporadically the styles are lost. It looks like it has something to do with timing, which makes it hard to replicate. Could it be because the success event is not final enough to reapply the jQuery to the buttons?

Btw, that is as long as there is only HTML content in the php-file. Like this:

```
<div id="main">
    <h2>This is a Button</h2>
    <button id="button">My Button</button>
</div>
```

As soon as I start adding some php-code (the PHP functions OK in the container), the styles are lost forever.

Is there a conceptual mistake that I am making? Any idea what throws off the jQuery? Or any suggestions how to properly restore the button?

Btw, I don't really care about the style of the buttons, it is more fundamental because I plan to use more of the jQuery in the `div` going forward.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should instead try using it in a callback from the `.load()` call like this:

```
 $('#menu li a').click(function(){
        $('#main').load('load.php ' + $(this).attr('href'), function()
        {
            $("#button").button();
        });
        return false;
    });
```

This works for me every time.